# Extracting a list of hyperlinks

Tags: jquery, functional-programming, dom, coffeescript

I need to produce a list **objCollector** with some results:

```
objCollector = []

      allRows.each () ->
        obj =
          source: self.source
          url: ''
          host: ''

        currentTag = $(this)
        links = currentTag.find('a')
        getTextFromSpan = currentTag.find('span.lnk').text()
        extractedLink = links[0].attribs.href
        obj.url = self.baseUrl + extractedLink
        obj.host = getTextFromSpan

        objCollector.push obj
```

Instead of building the result by appending to an empty list, could this be done more elegantly by using something like `map`?

Comment: @NickUdell this code is not broken! it just needs for refactor and code review

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just moved things around to make it a bit more readable. You can use the `map` function instead of `each`. The signature of map is as follows:

1. element in array
2. index of element
3. the array itself

I've added those parameters in the coffee script, but you could have easily done without them for a cleaner look. I assumed that `self` is some kind of global variable or variable available to the inner scope of the `map`.

See the [Mozilla article on map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map). It's fantastic!

```
objCollector = allRows.map (element, index, context) ->
  tag = $(element)

  text = tag.find('span.lnk').text()
  link = tag.find('a').first().attribs.href

  {
    source: self.source
    url: self.baseUrl + link
    host: text
  }
```